# Rails 3 / Passenger - uninitialized constant Bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

running: ruby 1.8.7-p358, rails 3.0.3, rvm 1.10.3, passenger, apache

I copied a rails project directory from one server to another.  Created its database - imported dump.sql,  Updated apache.conf for passenger link, ran touch tmp/restart.txt

Receiving error:

```
uninitialized constant Bundler
```

I have already tried:

```
'gem install bundler'
'bundle install' 
 deleting Gemfile.lck file, 'bundle install'
```

Any other ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned you're using RVM, have you tried any of the steps listed here:
https://rvm.io/integration/passenger/ ?

Comment: I did see that page, but not sure that it applies to my situation.  I probably don't understand what it's saying, though...

Answer (score 0):

Check file permission of the bundle executable after you installed the bundler gem. For me, the executable is located at /usr/local/bin.